Neologism for gender transition and detransition
I'm wanting to translate the phrase "death before detransition" in a way that would not upset a modern Latin reader too much. The best I have so far is "Potius mori quam detransire", following the form of "Potius mori quam foedare". How does that read? Any other suggestions?
EDIT: Looks like detransire might be a false cognate and not quite have the meaning I want. Any suggestions? How about something like demutationem? I suppose that's suggesting transition rather than detransition. How about reddemutationem? demutationem retro? Potius mori quam demutari?
